# Unable to find Jenkins config.xml on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

Can some body tell me where can I find config.xml on ubuntu 14.

I am using tomcat8 and deployed Jenkins.war file under web app. While configuring security, I did mistake and now it's asking for username and password.

I stopped server, deleted Jenkin from webapp and satrted server with new Jenkins.war, but no luck still it's asking credentials.

From this site I came to know that we need to set

```
 <useSecurity> to false in config.xml,
```

but I am unable to find config.xml of my ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem few days back,

set useSecurity to false from true and restart the server

```
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

with this you can able to signup for Jenkin and use that user to login.

```
To find config.xml
```

file will be under users home directory. jenkin will create config file under .Jenkins directory.

you can use below command to find config file

```
find ~/ -type f -name "config.xml"
```

this will give path to config.xml file, If you have sudo access you can edit the file.

Answer (score 12):

I found mine at:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
```

The official documentation seems to be of no use. Literally.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it through snap/Discover in Ubuntu/Kubuntu, you'll find it at

```
/var/snap/jenkins/<version>/config.xml
```